# Datalist autocomplete shows only the option's value, instead of the content

Tags: html, web-component, html-datalist

If I type "New", in the dropdown I only see "NY", whereas it should be "New York", [as the documentation states](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-datalists-what-you-need-to-know-78024/).

I am not sure what the problem is, as this worked before.

I've tried it in Chrome and Edge, and they both don't work.

Has something changed in the actual component?

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsbin.com/wabesofile/edit?html,output).

```
<input list="countries">
<datalist id="countries">
   <option value="DE">Germany</option>
   <option value="FR">France</option>
   <option value="US">United States</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: There's no NY or New York in your code. Why would you expect to get New York and how are you getting NY by following the steps you've laid out?

Comment: It's because I chose it arbitrarily as an example. The problem is not in that.

Comment: It's typically a requirement to have your problem description match your MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

Choose to set either `value` or `textContent`, but not both.

```js
b.onclick = ev => console.log( i.value )
```

```html
<input id=i list="countries">
<datalist id="countries">
   <option>Germany</option>
   <option value="France"></option>
   <option value="US">United States</option>
</datalist>
<button id=b>Get value</button>
```

Note that with Firefox it will work differently: with the `textContent` displayed dropdown list, and the selected `value` in the `<input>` text field :-(

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was really good before where one could select the content, but get the hidden value for further processing. Why has this stopped working?

Comment: @Ivan i don't know i've never seen it working with both value and content. Maybe you coud use another attribute (ìd`for example) for processing.